# If $X+Y=x+y$ and $X-Y=z(x-y)$, express $X$ in terms of $x$ and $z$, and $Y$ in terms of $y$ and $z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Express $X$ in terms of $x$ and $z$, $Y$ in terms of $y$ and $z$ if
>   $$\begin{align}
> X+Y&=x+y \\
> X-Y&=z(x-y)
> \end{align}$$
>   where $z$ is a positive constant.

Attempts so far:

It's easy when $z=1$. I have tried shuffling the variables around trying to eliminate either $x$ or $y$ but I'm unsuccessful. I also tried to assume that $X=ax+bz+czx$, $Y=py+qz+rzy$ and tried to solve for $a$, $b$, $c$, but I couldn't.

Comment: I see that its easy when z=1. I have tried shuffling the variables around trying to eliminate either x or y but I'm unsuccessful.

Comment: I also tried to assume that X=ax+bz+czx and tried to solve for a,b,c but I couldn't

Comment: add your last comments to the question under "My attempt so far:"!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

the solutions of the system are, for generic $z$:
$$
X=\frac{x(1+z)+y(1-z)}{2} \qquad
Y=\frac{x(1-z)+y(1+z)}{2}
$$
so we can have $X=f(z,x)$ and $Y=f(z,y)$ only for $z=1$.

Comment: So you're saying unless z=1 we cannot express X as X=f(z,x)?

Comment: Yes, if $x$ and $y$ are independent.